# dotnet core openidconnect identityserver4 breaks logout method

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a simple dotnet core application using identitysever4 for authentication. Login works fine. Logout works partially until i try to add a SignedOutCallbackPath. 
I added a method in home controller called logoutcomplete. I can call that method in the browser like so http://localhost:port/home/logoutcomplete. Then i add 
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = signedOutCallbackPath;
to the application and then run the app. then try to revisit http://localhost:port/home/logoutcomplete. It returns 200 but no view. It does not enter the controller method either.
Configure services are like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientId = clientId;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = metadataAddress;

            //options.SignedOutCallbackPath = signedOutCallbackPath;
            //options.SignedOutRedirectUri = Wtrealm + postLogoutUrl;
            // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
            // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL:
            //options.Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44321/";
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = onRedirectToIdentityProvider;
            //options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = onRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut;

            options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = remoteAuthFail;

            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");

            //options.Scope.Add("role");

        });              Services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

this is the configure method

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
Yes i have post logout redirect configured to the controller i mentioned. Here is the general over view of network tab in chrome after i perform step 1

1. I click the logout link in client app.
2. The logout controller handles it.
3. It logs me out of app and redirects me to ID server logout process.
4. Id server endsesssion is called. It redirects to ID server account/logout method.
5. It returns 302 to my postlogouturl page in my client. Which is where it should stop and i would be super happy.
6. But INSTEAD i get 302 from that postlogout destination.
7. and it sends me to the client home page. which has a challenge in code to ID server to login.

   Har file is too to post but here is the fetch version of the network tab in chrome

**Call 1:**
     https://localhost:44321/Account/Logout", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 2:**
    https://localhost:5001/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44321%2FAccount%2FCompleteSignout&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkZGQzU0RUYzRjlCODYzMUVDQTMyQThERUZDMjM1QjJFMTAzMTIwMjgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJfOFZPOF9tNFl4N0tNcWplX0NOYkxoQXhJQ2cifQ.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.rykZoW4oBhC8FB-6plAu8tlnsi9kqp4Ij7aSc3GahSngXQZTFR6thStpnQDB5AGvr3mTg9IYkHmd_H5Q6KpMXLCvP8icfIoPo0F82Hy5m9R1bHCr-2j3nz3-KKtD63-TAWJdH291v9ob5u2LDxeV3kax0oI-2_jlQmaR4FvKoEIOLTv3O07gJ7gGOqTMUXyxgPe8leTKVMsibG4LyIIeM0CbSSHA7cuEOu8VaCHLHh4mewPprmvcAXqRtjksT5SdlcuySt8Jm9j0u03qQV9XcXaf4XVE8vMdBgwP2dCjz4F7CYwJNRlZIGiTkVbFy1pRSJx9YNHyM-zMe3jvk9a11w&state=CfDJ8IkQZhXHRoVImqJIMbA3AwywYZQb1BcuwxT_DXXCkTLUmtShNjh8kb-IwB-Xdt3k-GOwwhKn2NFKH0e9YNp7QQBa65K6buhh-2ndhP6RsoIzOokn2jibJVRALgCTgGDHS_ubXnpUUGQlteboyzGPAWHQIny6XUv6jPS-BLpd6nuU&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 3:**
    https://localhost:5001/Account/Logout?logoutId=CfDJ8IAxOFzkPDhIhK9DJ2tWINzkHt_UeEMkRoNAXbQ6CosU_t3gC5V0MujllavlrQsVycb_3pHr62VvRY1EQDgy-aZ7bqcwmgETDaB3Zp1RXLmb15CG-S8WN8EBThjPZQ5-4QqSWgXi7G44Bvp2hW1vlmfLtcyTQ-U2QbPpQOsoccnXqUM4JfI41fmIUlIC2DHCyLYAbHsTwvf1g_twwr0Ed914NInq-35IoLEWjIxoDNeFfSJJoxasEl9klvK_1EM_hz2GTLMRP5s46jtuMSoebvG_EVwO9hFxRGNg2kS8llFqx2zjSjFqeqowTPv7yK3im7IHFVqCJWVvyOHXH7XKCddUSfH5SNQ1hf6I3Ag96G7BRgyWwFM_c_t560V5ihQXkQ3HT0JIyF5rbh5tFC370XtqPFzz5jFB7XOe6YveXnCCk3EPpRS9Ll7DCMCABnd5uLmh9i0WtZlVg_LA9KOXcy1x97VUqiMDxqW8h8ahM3YKz0UCnvvyGGM9TV0Cv-7RCqcEo9sJyDSYjQzCV6ZqyXylaaqftAyCTKaBlC3umI9Y-_CQw_7U86uMu8c7zvxiwcGj4ixJcKHVGmkV9x0G_F_DmrcBC1GJRlJR6jc-VBecK_PA24UiSk2Jjpgpa1CfZqXHAkEVNILzgKh2gGJU4gvqrTgpxGoQj5Hnz2Vl6Tadin6_w6RLRYZIz9Yd1F45Apkonntl8DwnrY6xzqLRFX3wQ7rkxQe_xWVZq-5oQCJ1QQFEHtVqtdvVHkDZFLVJXmQSF-S8yyxZn8WVE257iQCNHeVBSV8IjNT4HRHnGnsR15vMBpmOt7Co2UsHZPMY9dsajHfJtDrL9W4k4zIrKP7wScmdb9i8cdxZ8hjIr0Dfs_ZTswCuxgP-jZroKBCCOhJ9_k4K1lDYoAAKr09etztiwtFqMnq96O8-GtQYKVhZL9bYGSbVcLsm1ko_144vf0h5LdlkCcWUoP0fh0lOxwn80s9Gmtrend9jmuXDKZ_P", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 4:**
    https://localhost:44321/Account/CompleteSignout?state=CfDJ8IkQZhXHRoVImqJIMbA3AwywYZQb1BcuwxT_DXXCkTLUmtShNjh8kb-IwB-Xdt3k-GOwwhKn2NFKH0e9YNp7QQBa65K6buhh-2ndhP6RsoIzOokn2jibJVRALgCTgGDHS_ubXnpUUGQlteboyzGPAWHQIny6XUv6jPS-BLpd6nuU", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 5:**
    https://localhost:44321/", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 6:**
    https://localhost:5001/connect/authorize?client_id=776ae6c3-c273-4e8c-9f9a-18e39405cc7d&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44321%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636875657052545628.OTAwYzMwMWYtNzRmMi00YzlhLWFhNzgtMjRmZjFkOTgxYzY3YTBiMzcxMWUtM2M5Mi00YWE1LTkwNDgtNjIwODZjNDMxMDhk&login_hint=user.name&state=CfDJ8IkQZhXHRoVImqJIMbA3AwzSzO3TsIn08Q4MFv1bS3bVSAI8e35pZwTGfspMlXdIf3-lejQgu5bHYbbBYbPaR7S_20VO-GTp97rGCnsGeeQEuOqEGpYSA6C4LUeGCEYPV0R113XvY6qxcupAklxj_SVSwR3YWXKl2b-vwpkB45q8txV0TOc8LMeKbajQYB6jzQI5wI6b_zqRaAb0NHLRc4pk6fdx9PyVDouuq8mtfhKGaF1R0bV5iY1v8jkF4MEspx3xmL1Z78ik4YzRv1cgT52OvUvHgrnq9XgGfB5SXwI_e16CkuNZEf2ltVH5ifK5cA&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 7:**
    https://localhost:5001/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3D776ae6c3-c273-4e8c-9f9a-18e39405cc7d%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44321%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%2520offline_access%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D636875657052545628.OTAwYzMwMWYtNzRmMi00YzlhLWFhNzgtMjRmZjFkOTgxYzY3YTBiMzcxMWUtM2M5Mi00YWE1LTkwNDgtNjIwODZjNDMxMDhk%26login_hint%3Duser.name%26state%3DCfDJ8IkQZhXHRoVImqJIMbA3AwzSzO3TsIn08Q4MFv1bS3bVSAI8e35pZwTGfspMlXdIf3-lejQgu5bHYbbBYbPaR7S_20VO-GTp97rGCnsGeeQEuOqEGpYSA6C4LUeGCEYPV0R113XvY6qxcupAklxj_SVSwR3YWXKl2b-vwpkB45q8txV0TOc8LMeKbajQYB6jzQI5wI6b_zqRaAb0NHLRc4pk6fdx9PyVDouuq8mtfhKGaF1R0bV5iY1v8jkF4MEspx3xmL1Z78ik4YzRv1cgT52OvUvHgrnq9XgGfB5SXwI_e16CkuNZEf2ltVH5ifK5cA%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD2_0%26x-client-ver%3D5.3.0.0", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","cache-control":"no-cache","pragma":"no-cache","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrer":"https://localhost:44321/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

**Call 8,9,10,11:(all css and js calls useless for the purposes)**
    https://localhost:5001/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css", {"credentials":"omit","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}
    https://localhost:5001/css/site.css", {"credentials":"omit","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}
    https://localhost:5001/icon.png", {"credentials":"omit","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}
    https://localhost:5001/lib/jquery/jquery.js", {"credentials":"omit","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}
    https://localhost:5001/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js", {"credentials":"omit","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"}

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code to some controller to trigger the sign-out:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut("Cookies", OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

This will clear the local cookie and then redirect to IdentityServer. IdentityServer will clear its cookies and then give the user a link to return back to the MVC application.

Here is the client config in Identity Server :

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,


    RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:64146/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:64146/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        //Another scopes
    },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true
}
```

And you could set `options.SignedOutCallbackPath` to make user redirect after sign out of OIDC .

Comment: I have all this. This is not about triggering signout. I can do that from a logout method you just mentioned. The problem is the post logout redirect. It never get's back to the logoutcomplete method after ID server logs me out. Which is the whole weirdness.

Comment: Do you config the `PostLogoutRedirectUris ` in IDS4 , and confirm user is redirect to IDS page for sign out , also please show the network trace if possible .

Comment: Yes it is configured. I added a short version of the trace to the post.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? I'm having very similar issue at the moment.